# How to fix the scrollbars in Mac

Tags: macos, mac, osx-mountain-lion

Recently the scroll bars in all my applications on mac are growing larger when I hover over them and then covering the last item in lists (like Finder). Does anyone know how to turn this option off or in general if apple were to ever read this know of a better way to do this?

I think I would rather there be space at the bottom of the list for the scroll bar than for the scroll bar to covered the row (it can still remain hidden until necessary).

[image: selecting bottom row]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In *System Preferences » General* you can select *Show scroll bars: Always*. If you select that, applicable scrollbars are always displayed in their dedicated area, and don't resize when the pointer hovers over them.

[image: Screenshot of scroll bars]

Comment: Great! That fixed it!

Answer (score 2):

It's one of the [new features in Mountain Lion](http://www.apple.com/osx/whats-new/features.html#system):

> **Improved scroll bars**
>
> Scroll bars in Mountain Lion expand when you hover the cursor over them, so it’s easier to scroll a web page or document.

I tried searching for hidden preferences for disabling it, but didn't find anything.

`for f in $(mdfind kMDItemContentType==public.unix-executable -onlyin /System/Library/); do strings "$f" 2> /dev/null | grep -E '^[[:alnum:]_.-]{10,80}$' | grep -i scroll | sort -u | sed "s/^/${f##*/} /g"; done`

Comment: I find it's getting in the way. What does "for f in $(mdfind kMDItemContentType==public.unix-executable..." mean?

Comment: It's just the shell command I used for finding keys for hidden preferences. (I only tested a few of them though, so others could also give it a shot.)

Comment: FWIW, `defaults read -g AppleShowScrollBars` is either `WhenScrolling`, `Always`, or `Automatic`. Maybe that helps determining how it's used?